# Error during compile linux kernel module with clang: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-variable';

Tags: kernel, clang, kernel-module

I made example module and it compile very well with gcc. But when I try to compile with clang, it report error and stop. How can I solve this problm?
This is my Makfile:

```
obj-m += example_module.o
DIR = $(shell pwd)
KERNEL_DIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(DIR) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(DIR) clean
```

I try this command:
`make CC=clang HOSTCC=clang`

and this is error message.

```
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-variable'; did you mean '-Wno-unused-const-variable'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

and kernel version is this:

```
Linux <myname> 5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 10:28:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What kernel are you talking about? Linux?

Comment: @arrowd yes Linux. It's my mistake. I edit my question.

Comment: Remove it (that warning option) from *Makefile* and start again.